# If $G / N$ is a $\pi$-group, then $O^{\pi}(N) = O^{\pi}(G)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group and $\pi$ a set of primes, then $O^{\pi}(G)$ denotes the smallest normal subgroup such that $G / O^{\pi}(G)$ is a $\pi$-group (i.e. a group such that its order is only divided by primes from $\pi$). If $N \unlhd G$ is another normal subgroup such that $G / N$ is a $\pi$-group, then $O^{\pi}(G) \le N$.

Now let $N \unlhd G$ be such that $G / N$ is a $\pi$-group, then we have $O^{\pi}(G) \le N$ and also $N / O^{\pi}(G) \le G / O^{\pi}(G)$ is a $\pi$-group, hence $O^{\pi}(N) \le O^{\pi}(G)$. But
$$
 |G : O^{\pi}(N)| = |G : N||N : O^{\pi}(N)|
$$
is also a $\pi$-group, so $O^{\pi}(G) \le O^{\pi}(N)$. Combining we get $O^{\pi}(G) = O^{\pi}(N)$ in case $N \unlhd G$ is such that $G / N$ is a $\pi$-group.

Is this true? Is my reasoning right?

As a corollary we would get easily that if $H \unlhd\unlhd G$ is subnormal such that $|G : H|$ is a $\pi$-number, then $O^{\pi}(H) = O^{\pi}(G)$, hence $O^{\pi}(G) \le H$ in particular. For if $k$ denotes the length of a subnormal series $\{U_i\}_{i=1,\ldots, k}$ for $H$ in $G$. If $k = 1$ then it is the above result, if $k > 1$ and
$$
 H = U_0 \unlhd U_1 \unlhd \ldots \unlhd U_{k-1} \unlhd U_k = G.
$$
Then $O^{\pi}(U_0) = O^{\pi}(U_1) = \ldots = O^{\pi}(U_k)$ by applying the above to each pair of groups $U_i \unlhd U_{i+1}$ as $|U_{i+1} / U_i|$ is always a $\pi$-group.

Is this all right? I nowhere read about such a conclusion, so it would be nice if you just confirm if I am right, or maybe I have overlooked something? Or say if this is just trivial.

Comment: It seems that your argument true. I am not sure how much it is trivial but it seems to me that it is a natural result.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But do you know a different proof, a reference or something? You noticed my other recent post.