# If $H$ is subnormal in $G$ and its index is a $\pi$-number, then $O^{\pi}(G) \le H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\pi$ be a set of primes, then we call $n \in \mathbb N$ a $\pi$-number if it only contains prime divisor from $\pi$. If $G$ is a finite group, a $\pi$-group is a group whose order is a $\pi$-number. For $\pi = \{p\}$ these are the $p$-groups.

Denote the $O^{\pi}(G)$ the smallest normal subgroup such that $G / O^{\pi}(G)$ is a $\pi$-group (this is sometimes called the $\pi$-residuum). If $N \unlhd G$ is normal such that $G / N$ is a $\pi$-group, then we have $O^{\pi}(G) \le N$.

Could this last property extended to subnormal subgroups? A subgroup $H \le G$ is called *subnormal* if we have sequence of subgroups $U_i$ such that
$$
 H = U_0 \unlhd U_1 \unlhd U_2 \unlhd \ldots \unlhd U_{k-1} \unlhd U_k = G
$$
where each $U_i$ is normal i $U_{i+1}$.

> If $H$ is subnormal in $G$ (denoted by $H \unlhd\unlhd G$) and $|G : H|$ is a $\pi$-number, do we have that $O^{\pi}(G) \le H$?

EDIT: I already worked out a proof, but I would like to see another proof as I am skeptical about my result (I can find it nowhere stated, but if it would be true I guess someone else would have written it somewhere, at least as an exercise). In the other post I asked about confirmation (maybe this is a little bit to blurry to ask for) , but here I ask specifically for a proof or counter-example. See the comments. Also in my other question I asked about another result from which this one would follow. The other related question could be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1577029/if-g-n-is-a-pi-group-then-o-pin-o-pig).

Comment: Yes, but I am interested in other proofs; also I am still a little bit unsure about my result, so if someone post his proof this would be a great help. I edited my question.

Comment: your proof is true. In anyway you should give a link to avoid repeat. If $N$ is any normal subgroup, what is $N\cap O^{\pi} (G)$. I expect that it is equal to $O^{\pi}(N)$. If you have time think about it.

Comment: One side is clear I guess, easy to get $N\cap O^{pi}(G)\geq O^{pi}(N)$

Comment: You should prove the stronger result that $O^\pi(G) = O^\pi(H)$, which is a straightforward induction on $k$ using the result for $k=1$.

Comment: Thanks. That exactly the way I did it! For mesel's suggestion I do not see that $O^{\pi}(N) \ge N \cap O^{\pi}(G)$ for arbitrary $N \unlhd G$.

Comment: I guess I found a counter-example to mesels suggestions: Consider $D_6$ with the normal subgroup $N = \langle r \rangle$ generated by all rotations. Then $O^{3}(D_6) = D_6$ as the only normal subgroups have order $2, 3$ and $6$. But $O^{3}(N) = \langle r^2 \rangle$. So we have that $\langle r^2 \rangle = O^3(N) < O^3(D_6) \cap N = N$ is a proper inclusion.

Comment: o yes. So only one direction is true. $N\cap O^{\pi}(G)\geq O^{\pi} (N)$

Comment: The reason why I expect this, $N\cap O_{\pi}(G)=O_{\pi}(N)$.

Comment: Yes, that is true. As $N \cap O_{\pi}(G)$ is a $\pi$-group in $N$ we have $N \cap O_{\pi}(G) \le O_{\pi}(N)$. Conversely as $O_{\pi}(N)$ is characteristic we have $O_{\pi}(N) \unlhd G$, so that $O_{\pi}(N) \le O_{\pi}(G)$, which gives $O_{\pi}(N) \le O_{\pi}(G) \cap N$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an exercise problem found in the Martin Isaacs' Finite Group Theory book. I will just copy part of [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2586493/normalizer-of-subnormal-subgroup-problem-2-a-9-from-fgt/2586524#2586524) to another question on the site.

Work by induction on $|G|$. The base case is trivial, as well as the case when $K=G$. So assume that $K < G$. Then there exists $N \lhd G$, s.t. $K \lhd \lhd N$. Also $[N:K]$ is a $\pi$ number, so as $N$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, by the inductive hypothesis we have that $O^{\pi}(N) \le K$.

Now $O^{\pi}(N) \text{ char } N \lhd G \implies O^{\pi}(N) \lhd G$. We know that $[G:N]$ is a $\pi$ number so $|G/O^{\pi}(N)| = |G/N||N/O^{\pi}(N)|$, which is a $\pi$ number, so $G/O^{\pi}(N)$ is a $\pi$-group. But we know that $O^{\pi}(G)$ is contained in all normal subgroups of $G$, whose factor groups are $\pi$-groups, so $O^{\pi}(G) \le O^{\pi}(N) \le K$ and hence the proof.