# Normalizer of subnormal subgroup. Problem 2.A.9 from FGT by Isaacs

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

I try to solve problem **2.A.9** from M. Isaacs *Finite Group Theory* (FGT). I give it here.

> Let $G$ be a finite group and $\pi$ be a set of primes. Let $H$ be a subnormal subgroup of $G$ and assume that
>   $H=O^{\pi}(H)$, where $\pi$ is the set of primes. Show that
>   $O_{\pi}(G)$ normalizes $H$.

I explain the notations.

$O^{\pi}(H)$ is the **smallest** normal subgroup of $H$ such that $H/O^{\pi}(H)$ is a $\pi$-group (that is every prime, which divide the order of the group $H/O^{\pi}(H)$) is contained in $\pi$).

$O_{\pi}(G)$ is the **largest** normal  $\pi$-subgroup of $G$.

I try to use the standard approach using induction on $|G|$. But this does not lead to success. Maybe there is another approach in this problem?

Comment: There is a typo in the book. The hint reads: _Show in this case that $H=O^\pi(H)$_. It should say $H=O^\pi(G)$ instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Work by induction on $|G|$. As in the given hint assume that $G=HO_{\pi}(G)$. Indeed if this isn't true then by the inductive hypothesis in the group $HO_{\pi}(G)$ we have that $O_{\pi}(G)$ normalizes $H$ .

Now we have that $H \lhd \lhd G$ and $[G:H]$ is a $\pi$ number. So by problem **2A.2** we have that $O^{\pi}(G) \le H$. But now $O^{\pi}(G) \lhd H$ and $H/O^{\pi}(G)$ is a $\pi$ group, which implies that $O^{\pi}(G) = O^{\pi}(H) = H$. Now obviously $H = O^{\pi}(G) \lhd G$ and so $O_{\pi}(G)$ normalizes $H$ .

---

[UPDATE]: Solution of the problem **2A.2** in the book.

> **2A.2** If $K \lhd \lhd G$ and $[G:K]$ is a $\pi$ number, show that $O^{\pi}(G) \le K$.

Work by induction on $|G|$. The base case is trivial, as well as the case when $K=G$. So assume that $K < G$. Then there exists $N \lhd G$, s.t. $K \lhd \lhd N$. Also $[N:K]$ is a $\pi$ number, so as $N$ is a proper subgroup of $G$, by the inductive hypothesis we have that $O^{\pi}(N) \le K$.

Now $O^{\pi}(N) \text{ char } N \lhd G \implies O^{\pi}(N) \lhd G$. We know that $[G:N]$ is a $\pi$ number so $|G/O^{\pi}(N)| = |G/N||N/O^{\pi}(N)|$, which is a $\pi$ number, so $G/O^{\pi}(N)$ is a $\pi$-group. But we know that $O^{\pi}(G)$ is contained in all normal subgroups of $G$, whose factor groups are $\pi$-groups, so $O^{\pi}(G) \le O^{\pi}(N) \le K$ and hence the proof.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan. My crux was that I firstly tried to show that the equality $G=HO_{\pi}(G)$ is always true. Analyzing your solution I find that one can prove the stronger inclusion  $O_{\pi}(G)\subset H$ by the same way. Is not it?

Comment: Mikhail I'm utterly sorry, but in the second part $\pi$ should be in the superscript (up), not in the subscript (down). It was a typo, as the logic in the proof remains the same. Fixed now, though.

Comment: @MikhailGoltvanitsa I don't believe that the assertation $G= HO_{\pi}(G)$ is always true. I mean take $G= \mathbb{Z}_{30}$, $H = \langle 6 \rangle$ and $\pi = \{2\}$. Obviously $H \lhd G$ and $H =  O^{\pi}(H)$, as the order of $H$ is coprime to $2$. Also $O_{\pi}(G) = \langle 15 \rangle$ and obviously $G \not = HO_{\pi}(G)$. The same example contradicts your second assertation, which I believe was caused by my sloppy writing.